# Validation Exception in AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

While setting up AWS Code Pipeline as followed by the [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-ec2-create.html), I run into this error during the `BlockTraffic` event of the CodePipeline:

```
com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivityTaskFailedException: A validation exception from AWS Elastic Loadbalancing was received.
for activityId="5" of activityType={Name: ExecuteCentralizedCommandOnInstanceActivity.runCentralizedCommand,Version: 1.00}
```

Which fails to run the deploy. Is there any knowledge of a fix to this issue?

Comment: What is a block traffic event? I don't see the word "block" in the tutorial you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to appear during CodeDeploy deployment. Please check CloudTrail around the time of deployment failure and receiving this error. Look for Event Source as 'elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com' in CloudTrail. There will be some sort of 'ValidationException' that will help you find the root cause of the error. Most probably you have some typo in Load Balancer related settings.